# Can't change font-size of radio button

Tags: css, radio-button

I want to reduce the size of the font in my radio buttons as they are taking up too much space on mobile app. I tried to do inline styling and it did not work. I'm using jquery mobile 1.3 and when I was using jquery mobile 1.2, I had no problem changing font-size. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div data-type="horizontal">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <legend>I am a </legend>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                         <input type="radio" name="rad-User-Type-1" id="rad-User-Type-1" value="driver" checked="checked" data-theme="c" />
                         <label for="rad-User-Type-1"style="font-size:12px" >Driver</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                         <input type="radio" name="rad-User-Type-1" id="rad-User-Type-2" value="passenger"  data-theme="c"/>
                         <label for="rad-User-Type-2" style="font-size:12px">Passenger</label>
                    </div>                    
                </fieldset>

            </div>
```

Comment: What I mean is, I changed the jquery mobile css and javascript from 1.2 to 1.3 version

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect styles with Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) and see/edit styles in real time to find the solution.

Comment: I think a parent-style crash your label style, please investigate this with firebug :)

Comment: After using Firebug, I saw that I needed to assign the style to the label which uses the class ui-btn-text [label .ui-btn-text] instead of inside the label tag as span tags were dynamically created housing the text in the radio buttons and it used the class ui-btn-text

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<label for="rad-User-Type-1"style="font-size:12px" >Driver</label>
```

To:

```
<label for="rad-User-Type-1"style="font-size:12px !important" >Driver</label>
```

And let us know?

Comment: Isn't inline css properties area already higher in priority than user-defined and external stylesheets? That will not solve it.

Comment: @deadlock Yes. But if there is same rule with another `!important`.

Comment: Yep, Maybe. But that would be odd of JQM to make the user's life that hard.

Comment: Ha ha... Lets see if this fixes.

Comment: There is no space before `style`. Try giving a space.

Comment: I had a space before style

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-radio-on .ui-btn-text, .ui-radio-off .ui-btn-text{
    font-size:13px;
}
```